# Iterating over XML

Tags: powershell

I have some code that appears to work, in that it prints what I expect but it seems like there is at least one to many `foreach` statements.  I did initially have the same data in JSON but to make it work with PS2, I thought XML would make this easier.  The JSON version seemed rather simple in comparison.   The code is as follows as an example.  I would appreciate any input on if this is correct.  I'm convinced there must be a better way.

```
$xmldata = [xml]@"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
   <Components>
         <ITEM1>
         <name>
        <element>test1</element>
     </name>
     <info1>
        <element>info1-e1</element>
        <element>info1-e2</element>
     </info1>
     <info2>
        <element>info2-e1</element>
        <element>info2-e2</element>
     </info2>
    </ITEM1>
     <ITEM2>
     <name>
        <element>test2</element>
     </name>
     <info2>
        <element>info2-e1</element>
        <element>info2-e2</element>
     </info2>
     <info2>
        <element>info2-e1</element>
        <element>info2-e2</element>
     </info2>
     </ITEM2>
  </Components>
</DATA>
"@

$xmldata | Select-Xml -XPath "//DATA/Components" | foreach {
    foreach ($x in $_.node) {
        foreach ($itemToProcess in $x.ChildNodes) {
            Write-Host "Name:" $($itemToProcess.name.element)

            #Process Info1
            if ($itemToProcess.info1) {
                foreach ($e in $itemToProcess.info1.element) {
                    Write-Host "`tElement:" $e
                }
            }

            #Process Info2
            if ($itemToProcess.info2) {
                foreach ($e in $itemToProcess.info2.element) {
                    Write-Host "`tElement:" $e
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the answer or am I still missing a trick?  I have one less `foreach`.

```
$l1 = 0 
$l2 = 0

$xmldata | Select-Xml -XPath "//DATA/Components" | foreach {
    foreach ($itemToProcess in $_.node.ChildNodes) {
        Write-Host "Name:" $($itemToProcess.name.element)

        #Process Info1
        if ($itemToProcess.info1) {
            foreach ($e in $itemToProcess.info1.element) {
                Write-Host "`tElement:" $e
            }
        }

        #Process Info2
        if ($itemToProcess.info2) {
            foreach ($e in $itemToProcess.info2.element) {
                Write-Host "`tElement:" $e             
            }
        }
        $l2++
    }
    $l1++
}

Write-Host "Number of outer foreach" $l1
Write-Host "Number of inner foreach" $l2
```

Comment: The proper place to ask for critique on working code is [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Stack Overflow is for asking question about code that isn't working (yet). But to answer your question: yes, nesting one iterator in another iterator is pointless when both of them are essentially processing the same collection. Your second code sample is equivalent to your first one.

Comment: Thank you @AnsgarWiechers. I appreciate your time and input.